# $U[a,b]$ has maximum variance of any distribtuion on $[a,b]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm told that the uniform distribution has maximum variance amongst distributions of random variables taking values in $[a,b]$. That is, for any random variable $X$ with $P(X \in [a,b]) = 1$ we have, $\mathrm{Var}(X) \leq \frac1{12} (b-a)^2$.

I've tried some obvious things like $E[X^2] - (EX)^2 \leq b^2 - a^2$ but this isn't good enough. How can I prove the desired result? Note, if the result is false because I forgot some condition (e.g. you have to assume $X$ has a density) go ahead and assume what you need.

Comment: I suspect if you concentrate the pdf at $a$ and $b$, mean being $\frac{a+b}2$, you can push up the variance to $\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)^2$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the statement may not be correct. Consider an extreme case where $P(X=a)=0.5$ and $P(X=b)=0.5$. The expectation is $\mathbb{E}(X)=(a+b)/2$ and the variance is $Var(X)=(b-a)^2/4$, which is greater than your value..

Comment: Note that this particular measure has no Lebesgue-density, but you can generate a sequence of pdfs wich converge to this distribution, so the bound cannot hold uniformly even for the case of a Lebesgue-PDF.

Comment: Yes.  Because ${\sf Var}[X] = {\sf E}[(X-\mu)^2]$ , therefore any distribution on the support $[a;b]$ is going to have greater variance than a uniform distribution whenever points nearer the bounds have higher density than points nearer the mean.

Comment: In other words: $\cup$ shaped distributions will have higher variance that $\cap$ shaped ones.

Comment: Perhaps by "uniform" the person who told me meant the discrete $P(X=a) = P(X=b) = \frac{1}{2}$. Can we prove that $P(X=a)=P(X=b)=\frac{1}{2}$ maximizes the variance?